# NGinx split test two pages on same application instance

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to a/b (split) test two webpages on a single web application with a single hostname & instance.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. HTTP request for /
2. Request gets proxied to backend.app.com
3. Request is either proxied to backend.app.com/a or backend.app.com/b
4. Ideally that would be a sticky session that would maintain appropriate /a or /b during their session similar to what can be achieved with application pools.

Possible? Ideas?

Comment: SO is for asking specific questions. Not ideas or recommendations. Please refer to the Help Center to learn how ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`split_clients`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html#split_clients) directive.

Example from https://www.nginx.com/blog/performing-a-b-testing-nginx-plus/

```
http {
    # ...
    # application version 1a 
    upstream version_1a {
        server 10.0.0.100:3001;
        server 10.0.0.101:3001;
    }

    # application version 1b
    upstream version_1b {
        server 10.0.0.104:6002;
        server 10.0.0.105:6002;
    }

    split_clients "${arg_token}" $appversion {
        95%     version_1a;
        *       version_1b;
    }

    server {
        # ...
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://$appversion;
        }
    }
}
```

The `arg_token` in this case can be pretty much any variable you want.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused about how you would use arg_token to pass in two paths.

Comment: This is a general example for a general question. From here you would have to research the different possible ways to handle your use case. There are a lot of articles about `split_clients` so I wish you luck.

Comment: @DarrenBounds I think if you would use the combination of `$remote_addr` and `$remote_port` for hashing, nginx will use the same destination url (`/a` or `/b`) during the session, as you asked in your question.